# Intellij not able to connect to the SVN server

Tags: authentication, svn, ssh, intellij-idea-2016

I use Tortoise SVN for my subversion related operations. The Tortoise client uses putty I believe as the underlying engine to connect to the network. 
I have configured a private key in Putty which is synched with my public key loaded on the SVN server so that I do not have to provide username or password everytime I want to connect to the network to update, commit etc. for my project.

I would like to have the same set up with my intellij as well. I use IntelliJ 2017.2.2 version of the IDE and have the following settings under Subversion:

[image: Image_1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I am not even able to update, commit, annotate my project from Intellij. It keeps on asking for my username password and even after providing the username and password I still keep cannot connect i.e. I cannot update, commit etc.

My private key is in the openSSH format. It was generated using PuttyGen and private key from Putty.

I have also gone through the following questions and forums to find a solution to my problem.

[Link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620605/subversion-in-intellij-keeps-asking-for-authentication)

[Link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433388/intellij-idea-13-1-keeps-asking-credentials-for-svn)

[Link_3](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/authenticating-to-subversion.html)

[Link_4](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206820085-svn-authentication-issue-in-7905)

Comment: I have "Use command line client" and "Enable interactive mode" boxes checked. Also I had to use SVNKit instead of TortoiseSVN which uses JavaHL library (JavaHL doesn't work with our repo). As an "ssh executable" I have "putty.exe" (of course you have to give full path to putty.exe file). This configuration works for me - maybe you could try it too. (On a side note: I also tried "TortoisePlink.exe ssh -q" in Subversion config / SSH tunnel, but I'm authenticating with password now)